# Input and div side by side with input taking up all available width?

Tags: css

For a responsive site I want a div and an input to sit side by side, and I want the input to take up all the available width and not wrap onto the next line.

I want the div to be a fixed width or determined by its content, I dont want to set a % width for the div.

So I have this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
  <input value="something" >
</div>
.cont {
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
.stuff {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px
}
input {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap your input in a span and apply this CSS it should work:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5rFaV/1/)**

```
<div class="stuff">Some text</div>
<span><input type="text" value="something" /></span>
div {
    background: #00f;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to [support](http://caniuse.com/calc) IE9 or lower Use [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) property like this:

```
input {
  width:calc(100% - 100px);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDT5G/1/)

---

<sub>Complement with box-sizing to keep away issues with border and padding</sub>